# LINUX ls grep command

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to know What is the difference between the two command:

### ls l file; grep *pl file

### ls l file; grep ".*pl" file

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

First off - ";" is a command separator on shell. So the above will execute two different commands sequentially.

So that makes there are three different commands:

```
$ ls l file
```

This command will try to list two files namely "l" and "file". It will display the file names if they exist or error out if they do not.

```
$ grep *pl file
```

This is trickier. It will try to first replace * with the contents of the current directory. Whichever way it expands, it will append pl to it and try to grep that entire shell expanded pattern in the file. The output entirely depends upon the contents of your current directory.

```
$ grep ".*pl" file
```

This will do a greedy match of the pattern ".*pl" in the file. That means it will match all lines in the file which has a pattern:  followed by "pl"

Try this yourself and you would understand what's happening.